# JSlider last value

Tags: java, swing, jslider

When implementing JSlider's ChangeListener, the event is fired whenever the value changes.
I need to get the last value of a JSLider: I don't need every value visited by the slider, just the last value when the user releases the slider pointer.

Comment: Do you have any existing code which we could see?

Comment: There is no logic specific behavior. The code just implements the Change listener and prints the value, when the app run, I get all visited values on the std out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check getValueIsAdjusting() inside stateChanged function.

```
  JSlider source = (JSlider)e.getSource();
  if (!source.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
       ....
  }
```